# div array won't close when external close button div is clicked (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

I'm actually occurring a situation when making an accordion. I already add a close button (x text) inside my div to close the accordion, but it won't close after I clicked on that. Btw, my reference design is from https://dribbble.com/shots/6584063-Daily-UI-Accordion-Cards-Experiment. It's only the example of the behavior. Like in my reference, I don't want to have an active class on the first time. Then when clicked the other tab, the current active class is inactive, and have an external close button.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (e) => {

  const accordion = document.querySelectorAll('.a');
  const button = document.querySelectorAll('b');

  /* add Class from the div itself being clicked */
  accordion.forEach((accs, idx) => {
    accs.addEventListener('click', () => {
      addActive(accs, idx);
    });
  });

  function addActive(el, index) {
    el.classList.add('active');
    accordion.forEach((accs, idx) => {
      if (idx !== index) {
        accs.classList.remove("active");
      }
    });
  }

  /* remove class from button */
  button.forEach(xer => {
    xer.addEventListener('click', () => {
      removeActive();
    });
  });

  function removeActive() {
    accordion.forEach(accs => {
      accs.classList.remove('active');
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.toggle {
  display: none
}

.a .b {
  display: none;
}

.a.active {
  color: blue;
}

.a.active .b {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="1" class="a"> Source
  <div id="button-1" class="b"> x </div>
</div>

<div id="2" class="a"> Share
  <div id="button-2" class="b"> x </div>
</div>

<div id="3" class="a"> Report
  <div id="button-3" class="b"> x </div>
</div>
```

Please help me to fix that. Thank you so much.

Comment: IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document. Go and fix that error first of all.

Comment: You use ids instead of class, your `removeActive` function use `classList.add` instead of `classList.remove`. Also in your `addActive` function, add the active class after removing the class to the other so you avoid an if

Comment: already fix that in my codepen but still doesn't work

Comment: We don't have access to your pen, please edit your question with your improved code

Comment: Cedric : already fix that in my codepen, using class and in the removeActive function already change to classList.remove but doesn't work. Here's my codepen link https://codepen.io/Mhndrakhrisna96/pen/PoQYPqL

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please note that you should always strive to have a [mcve] _in the body of your question_-- [linking to offsite resources as the sole means of conveying an issue is problematic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/6831341).  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: Already inspected in the browser, the removeActive function is active, but it didn't do the job and the class which i want to remove is still active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two problems in your snippet:

1. `const button = document.querySelectorAll('b');` will select all `<b/>` elements, not elements with class `.b`; updated below to `const button = document.querySelectorAll('.b');`
2. Your close button is *inside* your accordion.  So, while your close function was working and removing the `.active` class, then the click handler for the accordion was triggering and immediately reopening it. Adding a [`e.stopPropagation();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) inside the handler stopped the event from bubbling up to the parent and resolved the problem.

See below for a working example:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (e) => {

  const accordion = document.querySelectorAll('.a');
  const button = document.querySelectorAll('.b');

  /* add Class from the div itself being clicked */
  accordion.forEach((accs, idx) => {
    accs.addEventListener('click', () => {
      addActive(accs, idx);
    });
  });

  function addActive(el, index) {
    el.classList.add('active');
    accordion.forEach((accs, idx) => {
      if (idx !== index) {
        accs.classList.remove("active");
      }
    });
  }

  /* remove class from button */
  button.forEach(xer => {
    xer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      removeActive();
    });
  });

  function removeActive() {
    accordion.forEach(accs => {
      accs.classList.remove('active');
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.toggle {
  display: none
}

.a .b {
  display: none;
}

.a.active {
  color: blue;
}

.a.active .b {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="1" class="a"> Source
  <div id="button-1" class="b"> x </div>
</div>

<div id="2" class="a"> Share
  <div id="button-2" class="b"> x </div>
</div>

<div id="3" class="a"> Report
  <div id="button-3" class="b"> x </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @alexander nied, you already saved my sleep time